# retrieve the model name for audit

Tags: django, python-2.7

Im building an audit app
and i need to retrieve the model name.
the thing is that i dont know the names of the models from the audit model
is there a way to refer to a generic model and get that name?

i already made a user log in/out model that saves the information in strings and i want to do something similar.

```
@receiver(user_logged_out)
def LogoutWatch(request,*args,**kwargs):
    Log = AuditoriaLog()
    Log.fecha = datetime.datetime.now()
    Log.usuario = request.user.usuario
    Log.nombre_u = str(request.user.get_full_name())
    Log.cedula_u = str(request.user.usuario.cedula)
    Log.actividad = "Cierre de Sesion"
    Log.save()
```

if i can get the model name there is a django function that stores the model in a dict, and then i can connect with the post save signal to get what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Using `type(object)` method you get a reference to the object type class. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).

That `type` class has an `__name__` attribute, which stores the class name.

Also, django models provide us two `_meta` attributes for the same proposal: `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural`. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#verbose-name).

So, you can use any of them:

```
print type(model).__name__
print type(model)._meta.verbose_name
print type(model)._meta.verbose_name_plural
```